# How to calculate vehicle distance using OMNet++ Vectors data?

Tags: omnet++

As I am working on a project on vehicle to vehicle communication, I need to calculate the distance between vehicle `node[0]` and vehicle `node[1]` for all given simulation time.

As there are `posx` and `posy` in the Vectors data, I can output them in `.csv` files, but the problem is that all data are separated into different csv files, for example, `node[0]` `posx` is in one file, but `node[0]` `posy` is in another.

I have to manually open two files and copy and paste the results together. Since there are four different value in each simulation, I have to open four different files each time.

If there are 20 different iteration on simulation, that means I have to open 80 files to get the distance between vehicles results that I want. Is there any faster and easier way that I can do this process?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to calculate the distance by looking at individual `.csv` files you can use more advanced tools like `R` (or the Rsutdio IDE) to merge the csvs in a bigger csv and then do your own calculations.

A better way of measuring the distance between two entities in Veins, is using the `distance()` function from the `Coord.h` class. This will compare two coordinates and provide the distance between them.

The code below should give you a rough idea of, although it does not apply exactly your case.

```
Coord eNodePos = Imobility->getCurrentPosition();
Coord selfPos = mobility->getCurrentPosition();
float distance = selfPos.distance(eNodePos);
```

Also you can use one of the `getDistance()` functions from the `TraCICommandInterface`. That might fit you better. The `TraCITestApp.cc` will give you an idea of how to use the functions.

If you need to compare the pairwise distance between more than two, than it is better for you to create a specific module in your simulation which will have a table where it collects the position of and id of the vehicles for each simulation second, and then output the distance between them in a vector.

Sorry, since your question lacks details of the code providing a ready-to-use solution is not possible.